# MonoDevelop opens Assembly.cs multiple times

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I seem to be experiencing some weird MonoDevelop behaviour, when opening the solution, rather than opening all the files I previously had open, it just opens Assembly.cs instead, meaning that it opens it as many times as I previously had windows open.  It's very annoying, it seems now to take about 5 minutes to open a solution.

Comment: I've checked the userprefs file and it contained about 100 entries for opening Assembly.cs, so I've deleted them and it works fine now, but I haven't a clue why it happened, is this a known defect?

Comment: I saw a similar problem yesterday - solved it by deleting userprefs - I think its a new monodevelop bug. I guess one of us should log it with xamarin... I will next time it happens - as then I can attach a userprefs before I delete it.

Comment: Never seen such behavior. It would be best to open a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach a (zipped) solution that show this.

Comment: It's stopped happening now I've deleted the offending lines, it's happened to two of my solutions though.